# Optimizing the speed of loop in a xts format in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

I have a data structured as xts like bellow:
[image]

The dimension is 2298 rows and 30 columns.
I want to do a loop in each row and column and store it in a new matrix/data frame. Considering the xts data as variable a, the sample code would be:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
 b[i,1] <- a[i,1]
  for(j in 2:ncol(a)){
   b[i,j] <- ((1+a[i,j])^j/(1+b[i,j-1]))-1
  }
}
```

As for loops are really slow in R, I wonder how can I speed this function up.

Comment: Try this; ta <- time(a); tb <- time(b); a <- coredata(a); b <- coredata(b); run loop; a <- xts(a, ta); b <- xts(b, tb)

Answer (score 1):

I think the slowness is due to the fact that you have not allocated memory for `b` before running the loop and also R uses vectorized operations and hence the `i` loop is not required:

```
system.time({
  b <- matrix(0, nrow(a), ncol(a))
  b[,1] <- a[,1]
  for(j in 2:ncol(a)){
    b[,j] <- ((1+a[,j])^j/(1+b[,j-1]))-1
  }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0
```

data:

```
#R-3.6.1 64bit Win10
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 2298L
nc <- 30L
library(xts)
a <- xts(matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), nr, nc), seq(Sys.Date()-nr, by="1 day", length.out=nr))
```